# how can I iterate through a text file by loop twice at the same time

Tags: python

I open a text file looking for a line beginning with 1.
once I found it I need to perform a calculation on the next 6 lines.
now, I need to continue to find the next line with 1 at the beginning.

```
lcuLogIn="C:\\Automation\\LcuLogs\\LCU_Log_6Ant_Test.log"
with open(lcuLogIn, 'r+') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(t):
            if line[0] == "1":
                local_counter = 0
                while local_counter < 6:
                    if local_counter == 0:
                        print "do something"
                    if local_counter == 1:
                        print "do something"
                    if local_counter == 2:
                        print "do something"
                    if local_counter == 3:
                        print "do something"
                    if local_counter == 4:
                        print "do something"
                    if local_counter == 5:
                        print "do something"
                    local_counter += 1
                i += 6
```

the index is not progressing, since it is the loop index.
I can't iterate twice - I'm getting an error "mixed iteration can cause loose data"

Comment: Can you show sample input file and expected result?

Comment: Change `if line[0] == "1":` to `if line[i].startswith("1"):`

Comment: If the file is not that long you could save it in a list with f.readlines()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are iterating over the file (`t` is `f`), you can use the [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to advance the file iterator within the loop.

```
lcuLogIn="C:\\Automation\\LcuLogs\\LCU_Log_6Ant_Test.log"
with open(lcuLogIn, 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith("1"):
                for i in range(6):
                    # Advance file iterator
                    line = next(f)
                    if i == 0:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 1:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 2:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 3:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 4:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 5:
                        print "do something"
```

If `t` is actually some other iterable, you can create an iterator using the [iter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function, and use that in the same way.

```
lcuLogIn="C:\\Automation\\LcuLogs\\LCU_Log_6Ant_Test.log"
with open(lcuLogIn, 'r+') as f:
        it = iter(t)
        for line in it:
            if line.startswith("1"):
                for i in range(6):
                    # Advance the iterator
                    line = next(it)
                    if i == 0:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 1:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 2:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 3:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 4:
                        print "do something"
                    if i == 5:
                        print "do something"
```

Comment: It won't work if you have less than 6 lines ahead of you.

Comment: @palvarez fair point, but the OP doesn't mention that this is an issue; I'd suggest that they are processing a file with a structure of one header line followed by six detail lines, so it's reasonable that the six lines will always follow, unless the OP tells us otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `t` is a list of lines

```
lcuLogIn="C:\\Automation\\LcuLogs\\LCU_Log_6Ant_Test.log"
with open(lcuLogIn, 'r+') as f:
    i = 0
    while i < len(t):
        line = t[i]
        if line[0] == "1":
            local_counter = 0
            while local_counter < 6:
                if local_counter == 0:
                    print "do something"
                if local_counter == 1:
                    print "do something"
                if local_counter == 2:
                    print "do something"
                if local_counter == 3:
                    print "do something"
                if local_counter == 4:
                    print "do something"
                if local_counter == 5:
                    print "do something"
                local_counter += 1
            i += 6
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Saving the lines in file in readlines() if the file is not that big, and adding a restriction for the length.

```
lcuLogIn="C:\\Automation\\LcuLogs\\LCU_Log_6Ant_Test.log"
with open(lcuLogIn, 'r+') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  total_lines = len(lines)
  for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith("1"):
      local_counter = 0
      while local_counter < 6 and (i + local_counter < total_lines):
          print(line, local_counter)
          if local_counter == 0:
              print "do something"
          if local_counter == 1:
              print "do something"
          if local_counter == 2:
              print "do something"
          if local_counter == 3:
              print "do something"
          if local_counter == 4:
              print "do something"
          if local_counter == 5:
              print "do something"
          local_counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer more elegant way of doing the same, then you can do the below.
The `log` in the for is a list and will contain the line that starts with "1" as its first element and the following 6 lines as its other elements in same order. Try to change the `input_file` variable with your file and run it to see the output.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

input_file = 'input_file.txt'
lines = open(input_file).readlines()

for log in filter(lambda x: x[0].startswith("1"), izip_longest(*[lines[i:] for i in range(7)])):
    print log[0]
    print '\t', log[1:]
```

In the above code, you will have to write the logic about what to do with the six lines following the line that starts with "1", inside the for loop.